# Color columns based on x axis and not on values (y axis) in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Trying to color columns based on x axis( negative, 0s and positives), just not able to do it. Tried several things.

Tried several options in fiddle.. but not able to do it.

Tried the zone method, added zones at all possible places.

```
zones: [{
        value: -3,
        color: 'red'
    }, {
        value: 0,
        color: 'orange'
    }, {
        color: 'green'
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rxnj0qc1/

No errors.. the colors just wont appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `zones` in a `series`:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{
        value: 10,
        color: 'red'
    }, {
        value: 12,
        color: 'orange'
    }, {
        color: 'green'
    }]
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mpxtqzsv/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.zoneAxis

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.zones